# Problems deleting a Meteor.js collection using template event listeners

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, events, meteor

I am relatively new to Meteor, and having some difficulties figuring this out, so perhaps someone can be kind enough to let me know what I am doing wrong.  I've created a list of items in a Meteor (mongo) collection available to client/server.  I'd like to delete the item that I have showing up next to the delete button. I've done this so far.  The first portion where I enter the data works fine, and the template List does show all my data:

In my html file (client/list.html)

```
<template name=List>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>Description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{{itemName}}</td>
      <td>{{description}}</td>
      <button class="btn" id="delete" type="submit">Delete</button>
    </tr>
</template>
```

On the js file (client/list.js)

```
Template.quickList.events({
  'click #delete': function(e, t){
    cl = Lists.findOne(t.data);
    Lists.remove({_id: cl._id});
  }
});
```

Note:  I get a null value in the events listener (in the list.js file) if I try *console.log(t.data)*

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events handled by a template's event map will have the template's data context available in the `this` keyword. If your item is the data context (and it likely is if you are getting `itemName` and `description` without helpers), you can just use `this._id` in the event handler.

```
<tr>
  <td>{{itemName}}</td>
  <td>{{description}}</td>
  <button class="btn" id="delete" type="submit">Delete</button>
</tr>
```

With the event:

```
Template.quickList.events({
  'click #delete': function(event){
    Lists.remove(this._id);
  }
});
```